# Mediaelement.js not playing mp3 in firefox 26 - it works everywhere else

Tags: mediaelement.js

You can see my problem in my dev box: dev5.r2rlive.com (we are developing for mobile first approach and right now we only have the layout for smartphones)

Mediaelement.js is working in most browsers but in Mozilla Firefox 26. I get an error on the console:

> HTTP "Content-Type" of "text/html" is not supported. Load of media resource correct_path_to_audio.mp3 failed.

The funny thing it that it was working before, so I tried to isolate the problem doing another test page where I take out some of the scripts on the page, but I do get the same results: the music wont play on Firefox but it works in IE and Chrome, here is the other test page: http://dev5.r2rlive.com/list_test

I added the `player.load()` line after reading some posts but that did not work.

Please let me know if you can help me spot the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was happening because my Flash Player was not in the right place. Therefore when the flash fallback was needed it wasn't found. I fixed it by changing the default URL for the Flash Player.